# magento 2 how dependency injection worked

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

I know this question is asked many time by another user but all of them describe "how we can use magento DI" ? they does not speak about how magento pass object that constructor method needed or how magento find  constructor need which object

Answer (score 0):

The **di.xml** file configures which **dependencies** are injected by the `object manager`. You can also specify `sensitive configuration` settings using di.xml

> **Magento loads the configuration in the following stages:**

- Initial (app/etc/di.xml)
- Global (/etc/di.xml)
- Area-specific (/etc//di.xml)

Comment: and magento  how to find which constractor need which object ?